# What is the combination of flatMap and filter?

Tags: scala

In scala collections, there is a collect method which is a combination of map and filter.

Is there another method which is a combination of flatMap and filter?

Here is what I am trying to do

```
val myList: List[Int] = ....
val x = myList.flatMap { id =>               
  val r : Option[List[Int]] = obj.foo(id)
  r
}
```

Right now the scala compiler tells me that the type of x is `List[List[Int]]`

But I want `List[Int]`

If I change my code to

```
val myList: List[Int] = ....
val x = myList.flatMap { id =>               
  val r : Option[List[Int]] = obj.foo(id).get
  r
}
```

Then I get what I want. but I don't want to do get. So I want a clean and concise way of doing a flatMap while filtering out the items which are None.

I can also do

```
val myList: List[Int] = ....
val result = myList.flatMap { id =>               
  val r : Option[List[Int]] = obj.foo(id).getOrElse(List[Int]())
  r
}
```

but that is still very verbose.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you're trying to filter while using `flatMap` you can easily do something like

```
List(1, 2, 3).flatMap {
  case n if n > 1 => List.fill(n)(n.toString)
  case _ => Nil
}
// result: List("2", "2", "3", "3", "3")
```

In your specific case:

```
myList.flatMap { id => obj.foo(id) match {
  case Some(list) => list
  case None => Nil
}}
```

Or even shorter

```
myList.flatMap(obj.foo(_).getOrElse(Nil))
```

Comment: Why not just `myList.flatMap(obj.foo).flatten`?

Comment: `flatten` is the right way for this task. It's concise, clear and exists exactly for this task.

Answer (score 1):

I think the **for** expression can do the trick:

```
val myList: List[Int] = ....
val x = for {
    id <- myList
    r <- obj.foo(id)
} yield r
```

Actually for expression is translated to `flatMap`, `map` and `filter` (see http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code would work perfectly if you would add `.flatten` to the end.

Here is how I would write it:

```
val x1: List[Int] = myList.flatMap(obj.foo).flatten
```

or if you for some reason really need `collect`, then as follows:

```
val x2: List[Int] = myList.map(obj.foo).collect{
  case Some(data) => data
}.flatten
```

---

The complete source is here:

```
object Test3 extends App {
  object obj {
    def foo(i: Int) = (0 to i).toList match {
      case Nil => None
      case nonEmpty => Some(nonEmpty)
    }
  }

  val myList: List[Int] = (0 to 3).toList
  val x = myList.flatMap { id =>
    val r : Option[List[Int]] = obj.foo(id)
    r
  }.flatten

  val x1: List[Int] = myList.flatMap(obj.foo).flatten
  val x2: List[Int] = myList.map(obj.foo).collect{
    case Some(data) => data
  }.flatten
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` can actually be expressed through `flatMap` if an empty state (`None`/`List.empty`) is known, so `flatMap` is more generic than `filter` (at least for `List`s and `Option`s). Your problem is that you need to apply it twice:

```
myList.flatMap(obj.foo).flatMap(x => x)
```

or just:

```
myList.flatMap(obj.foo).flatten
```

Just a simple note: if you have a type `List[List[T]]`, or more generally `M[M[T]]` and you want to get `M[T]` it usually involves `flatMap`/`flatten`

Example:

```
val obj = Map(1 -> List(1), 2 -> List(2, 3))
val l = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

scala> obj.get(1)
res1: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1))

scala> l.flatMap(obj.get)
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2, 3))

scala> l.flatMap(obj.get).flatten
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```